# 991px and less width twitter bootstrap 3 overlap some of the rows, and hide content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am using twitter bootstrap 3 for responsive design. I have a problem where I resize my window to 991px width, it is supposed to display them in vertical, but instead they overlap each other.
This first image show, how it looks in horizontal view, above 991px width the second and third image show you that it's broken when I go below 991px width.

[image: Good]

[image: Bad]

[image: Bad]

I am using `<div class="container-fluid">` which store few `<div class="row-fluid">` but also `<div class="row">` and tables, etc. I can upload full code on jsfiddle if that would help. I will also post a screen that coould possibly help you find an error.
[image]

Comment: You will need to either post the related code here or provide a link to your working site because screen shots alone are not enough for anyone to help you.

Comment: Delete the dots in class ;) div class should ="col-sm-" not =".col-sm-"

Comment: wow, deleting the dots fixed this :) Thanks alot ^^ You can make it an answer so I can accept it. i will test it and make sure its 100% working tho